# Errors while using Interfaces.C.Strings.Char_Array_Access

Tags: arrays, char, ada

I am working on a C-ADA binding project where I need to pass a String declared in ADA side to C functions. In one of the ADA function, I declared a bounded char array as:

```
Str_C : Interfaces.C.Char_Array(1..23) := (others => Interfaces.C.nul);
```

And declared a vector of type `Char_Array_Access` as:

```
Ptr1 : Interfaces.C.Strings.Char_Array_Access := Str_C'Access;
```

But the compiler fails to compile at the above mentioned vector initialization and says "prefix of "Access" attribute must be aliased"

(I didn't aliased the char_array previously because char_array type is already and aliased array of char).

OK, let's add aliased keyword to the char array declaration as:

```
Str_C : aliased Interfaces.C.Char_Array(1..23) := (others => Interfaces.C.nul);
```

but it still fails with an error on the vector line as:
[image]

and a warning on the char array declaration line as:
[image]

Don't know what is going wrong here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No, it is C-ADA binding,

Comment: Actually, it is the components of `char_array` objects that are **aliased** (character), but not the entire array objects of type `char_array` themselves. In the case of `char_array`, I imagine that the type matches C's way of referring to single characters of C arrays by pointer. As in `*(s+1)` for `s[1]`, for example, which shows how C "array" `s` is a pointer, to `char`, zeroth char, first char, second char, … of a string `s`.

Answer (score 1):

It is about the explict subtype constraints `1..23` on the left side, the subtype bounds on `Str_C`'s type `char_array`, I think. The (private) pointer type `chars_ptr` is to unconstrained objects without bounds, reflecting C's `char*` (which knows no bounds). So, declare the object like this:

```
Str_C : aliased Interfaces.C.char_array  := (1..23 => Interfaces.C.nul);

Ptr1 : Interfaces.
    C.Strings.chars_ptr := Interfaces.C.Strings.To_Chars_Ptr(Str_C'access);
```

`To_Chars_Ptr` does the necessary pointer conversion. The declarations actually reflect the compiler's diagnosis.

It might be worth considering `To_Ada`, `To_C`, and `Convention` identifiers, together with a language feature: Ada passes arrays to C functions as C pointers. This is documented in [LRM Annex B.3](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-B-3.html) (see *Implementation Advice*). So, you could store Ada strings, if you liked, on the Ada side.

Since the problem seems to also involve accessibility of pointed-to objects (e.g., of an array declared within a subprogram), here are some ways around that. See [LRM 3.10.2](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-10-2.html) for details. The important question to ask is: "Do the objects exist when pointers to them could still be passed around?" Making sure that objects exist after a subprogram is done, say, can be achieved by *allocating* the arrays in the subprogram, as opposed to declaring them as variables on the stack. (Stack variables will essentially be gone after the call). Or, if you **really** know what you are doing, you can force the compiler to ignore that a pointer may outlive its object by using `'Unchecked_Access` and not `'Access`.

```
Ptr2 : Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr :=   -- DANGER AHEAD!
  Interfaces.C.Strings.To_Chars_Ptr(Str_C'UNCHECKED_ACCESS);

Ptr3 : Interfaces.C.Strings.Chars_Ptr := Interfaces.C.Strings.To_Chars_Ptr
  (new Interfaces.C.char_array'(1..23 => Interfaces.C.nul));

Ptr4 : Interfaces.C.Strings.Chars_Ptr :=
  Interfaces.C.Strings.New_Char_Array((1..23 => Interfaces.C.nul));
```

Comment: I tried your code @B98 , but I am getting a compiler error "non-local pointer cannot point to local object" at Ptr1 declaration?

Comment: This says that your object was declared perhaps within in some subprogram, but is to be referenced via a pointer type that was declared at a more outer level (than the subprogram), like `chars_ptr` is (in the Ada library, couldn't get much more "outer"). This is a different, and quite general matter; I suggest you provide more context so that the issues can be treated separately. In particular: locally declared objects go away when the procedure is done, so if you take `'access`, you'd create a dangling pointer. Ada prevents that at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The function New-String is the perfect tool for what you want to do :

```
with Interfaces.C.Strings; use Interfaces.C.Strings;

procedure Main_Ada is

Nom : constant chars_Ptr := New_string("Charles Dupont");
...
```